# will installing canopy interfere with my current python setup?

Tags: python, installation, enthought, canopy

I have a working Python ecosystem on Ubuntu.

Now I want to try Enthought Canopy.  Will that installation mess up or interfere somehow with my current system?

Two examples to illustrate my confusion:

- will this installation overwrite libraries in my current setup?
- which python will start if I invoke `ipython` in a terminal?

Comment: I added two examples to clarify the specific problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it wont:

http://docs.enthought.com/canopy/quick-start/install_linux.html

> If the check box for making Canopy your default Python environment is checked the following line will be added your .bash_profile or .profile files:
>
> source ~/Enthought/Canopy_32bit/User/bin/activate

But you can always uncheck the box.